# How to customize Material-UI StepConnector

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize Material-UI StepConnector with classes, but it seems to not work.

I use material-ui 1.4.0

Here is how I try to do it.

```
       <Stepper
          connector={
            <StepConnector
              classes={{
                completed: { borderColor: "red" },
                line: { borderColor: "red" }
              }}
            />
          }
          activeStep={activeStep}
          orientation="vertical"
        >
```

Here is demo https://codesandbox.io/s/oxrw7ryy7z

As you can see the `StepConnector` color does not change at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StepConnector` doesn't have a `complete` class in v1.4.0, documentation for v1.4.0: https://v1-4-0.material-ui.com/api/step-connector/

If you want to change the color of the wole line try this:

```
// In your style
contentRoot: {
  borderColor: 'red',
},
connectorLine: {
  borderColor: 'red',
},

...

<StepConnector
   classes={{
     line: classes.connectorLine
   }}
/>
...
  <StepContent
     classes={{
       root: classes.contentRoot,
     }}
  >
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/p9wj1498yx

Answer (score 2):

Add a new class in your styles:

```
connector: {
  borderLeft: "1px red solid"
}
```

And then use it in your component:

```
<StepConnector
  classes={{
    line: classes.connector
  }}
/>
```

The `completed` class [does not appear](https://v1-4-0.material-ui.com/api/step-connector/#css-api) to be a class that can be overriden in this version.