# Material UI - Custom step connector on stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

can I have a custom connector on material ui stepper? Not a single line as connector but these arrows on image below.

[image]

Material ui version 4 + react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize Material-UI StepConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451265/how-to-customize-material-ui-stepconnector)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the connector by passing [any jsx element](https://v4.mui.com/api/stepper/#props)  to the `connector` property of `Stepper` component:

```
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';

...
<Stepper connector={<ArrowForwardIcon />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested from Dmitriif above on the answers sections **works** fine,

**but** the *arrow icons* will always be black or what ever current color is "svg css fill:current-color "

 ====>
**meaning that** color will not be affected if the step is active/completed/disabled etc ...

In order to get the classes of active/completed/etc triggered u need to wrap ur icon with a component that has those classes already ,

So I made this twist I **rapped** the **icon** with a stepLabel component so that it will already have MUI-active triggered when step is active ,

code:

```
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';

const ArrowIcon = () => {
return (
    <StepLabel 
    sx={{
        color: "#757e8d", //gray when disabled/inactive
        "& .MuiStepLabel-label.Mui-active": {
          color: "blue", // color icon blue (when active)
        }
      }}
    icon={<span />}> //mandatory, if removed numbers will show next to arrow
          <ArrowForwardIcon />
    </StepLabel>
      
);}
```

Now use the above component at ur stepper component :

```
<Stepper connector={<ArrowIcon />} />
```